# How to check RabbitMQ firehose is on or not

Tags: rabbitmq

I know if we use `rabbitmqctl trace_on` we can enable `firehose`
but, on `cluster mode`, we need `trace_on` each one.
Is there any way to know the `rabbitmq node trace` is on or not?

Which config can setting `trace_on` when `rabbitmq` startup?

Answer (score 0):

The [documentation](https://www.rabbitmq.com/firehose.html) states that the tracing plugin is off by default. There is no config setting to enable this feature, you must run `rabbitmqctl`. There is no harm in running `trace_on` if it is already on.

Finally, tracing should only be used for debugging, not in production.